# add vue.js single file component to js express server

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, webpack, twig

I have a website powered with express, serving twig rendered files.

I want to add vue.js with single file components (the .vue files)

Lots of tutorials are talking about webpack using the vue.js router to serve files.

The thing is I already have my express router serving files. I just want to create .vue components stored in my static directory and load them in my pages with nested components.

How can I do that simply ? Do i really need webpack ? And if i do, is there a simple way to add webpack to an existing express project to use single file components.

I'm new with vueJS and i don't really understand how it works.

Thank's a lot !